# In rails, what is the best way to add validation on selected attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model `User.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # on page 1 only this validations should call
  validate :first_name, presence: true
  validate :last_name, presence: true
  ..
  # on page 2 only this validations should call
  validate :email, uniqueness: true
  validate :phone, presence: true
  ..
  # on page 3 only this validations should call
  validate :salary, presence: true
  validate :category, presence: true
  .. 

end
```

I know I can use the validation `if/unless` condition but I have so many attributes.So here on page1 only page1 errors should be shown same as for page2 and so on.I've specified only a few attributes here they are more in numbers.So What would be the best way to add validation here according to page number

Comment: hope this will help http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: http://brains.rabid.co.nz/2014/09/29/rails-multistep-forms.html

Comment: You may want to use 'with_options'. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/42-with-options